# Adding missing property names with VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete

VSCode has a dropdown menu that autocomplete keys as I am typing them into source code of an object literal. For example the object literal `{ bar: 123 }` might be missing key `quux`. As I type `q` VSCode shows me a dropdown with property `quux`. This lets me know that `quux` is a defined property that is currently missing from the object literal. Now the problem is that I need to repeat this by typing every imaginable alphabet that might be the first character of a missing property name.

I'm looking for a feature that would let me add all missing property names with null values, so I would not have to find them one by one from the autocomplete menu. Being able to open the autocomplete menu without typing in any character might also be useful since this would let me see all properties regardless of their first character.

Comment: The sad thing about this is that the functionality is there to automatically add not nullable properties. The developers explicitly excluded nullable fields from that :(